# Preparations for SSL connection (HTTPS)

Tags: php, apache, security, http, ssl

I am getting a SSL connection for my website, meaning I can access it with HTTPS. This is the first time I did such a thing and I'd like to know the basic stuff I need to do on my script to make it work as it should with the new connection.

My website uses cookies and sessions. I also need to know how I should force the user to use HTTPS instead of HTTP (ie: redirect to HTTPS if the user used HTTP).

Thank you.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: This belongs on serverfault, it is not a programming question.

Comment: None of these answers helped you in any way? Really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to force SSL for A particular URL's then you can do something like this

Rewrite incoming URL's on port 80 with a particular pattern;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/PATH-YOU-WANT-TO-RESTRICT$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
```

You will also need to ensure that your apache server is listening for requests coming in on port 443. This can be done easily in your httpd.conf file;

```
Listen servername:443
```

You will also require a Virtual host on our Apache server;

```
LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so

<VirtualHost servername:443>
    SSLEnable
    ServerName servername
    SSLClientAuth None
    ErrorLog /servername/conf/ssl/logs/https-error_log
    RewriteEngine On
    Include conf/vanity_rules/vanity_rewrite_rules.conf
    KeyFile /servername/conf/ssl/yourkey.kdb
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration will ensure that the transport between browser and your Apache server is all encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in php, but you would actually be accepting the http connection to then run the script and proceed to send the redirect HTTP header programmatically.

Normally what you do is to configure whatever you are using you serve your php application (apache, nginx, ...) to do the redirect.

Comment: I am using apache. I tried a few solutions I found here on SoF but none worked, hence the question. I still require assistance on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to take care of:

1. Configure Apache for HTTPS. You will need to install the SSL certificate, and create a new virtual host for HTTPS, on port 443. This page has a good example of how to do that:

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts

1. In order to have access to the HTTP session via HTTPS, you will need to ensure that the same session ID is used in HTTPS as in HTTP. There are several ways of doing this, the most common being to send the session ID in the query string, then set the session ID on your HTTPS page using session_id();

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of the following things:

- get yourself a dedicated IP address for that website (in any normal case, you can't have name based virtual SSL hosts)
- get yourself a certificate from a high quality trusted provider
- make sure Apache can handle SSL requests (openssl, mod_ssl)
- configure your http vhost to redirect, if you want to force SSL only

  `Redirect permanent / https://yourdomain.com`
- configure your https vhost securely, make sure you know what you're doing regarding ciphersuits, etc. here is an example configuration (may not be exactly what you need, but similar):

  ```
  SSLEngine on
  Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=8640000;includeSubdomains"
  SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
  SSLCipherSuite 'ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:RC4+SHA1+RSA'
  SSLCertificateFile path/to/your.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile path/to/your.key
  SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \ 
      nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \ 
      downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  SSLCACertificateFile path/to/intermediate.ca
  ```